# How to solve invalid swagger warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, swagger, webapi

How may I solve this warning from swagger? I have two identical routes, one for get and another for put. This only occurs on homologation environment, in devevelopment environment there is no warning.

Warning message:

```
{"messages":["attribute paths.'/api/Notificacoes/{id}'(get).operationId is repeated"]}
```

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have more than one route specified for one method.

Comment: I have the same route for put and get. It can't be done for different verbs? Thanks